# Trying to implement Card Flip animation to fragments (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am trying to implement card flip animation to my fragments, I am following the tutorial at the Developer website http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

However I am getting a weird error, I downloaded the sample app from the Developer website, which to my amazement works fine but when I replace the code in my particular activity it gives me an error:

**The method setCustomAnimations(int, int) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int)**

Here is the problem code:

```
private View.OnClickListener on = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager  
                    .beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                            R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                            R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
            //Fragment1_2 fragment1_2 = new Fragment1_2();  
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, new Fragment1_2()); 
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();  

        }
    };
```

**Edit**
If I comment the first two or the last two arguments to setCustomAnimation, everything just works fine, however I dont get the animation back press which I know is an implementation issue. Below is the complete code of this fragment's class file:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment {
    MenuItem mMenuItem;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        //  actionBar.setSubtitle("mytest");
        actionBar.setTitle("Reminders"); 
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);




        Button b = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        b.setOnClickListener(on);
        b.setText("Check");
        return rootView;
    }
    private View.OnClickListener on = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager  
                    .beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                          //  R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out);
                            R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
            //Fragment1_2 fragment1_2 = new Fragment1_2();  
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, new Fragment1_2()); 
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();  

        }
    };

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater =getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        mMenuItem = item; 
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager  
                .beginTransaction();  
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.info:
            FragmentContact fragmentcontact = new FragmentContact(); 
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragmentcontact, "Fragment1_2");  
            mMenuItem.setEnabled(false); 
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();  
            break;

        default:

            break; 
        }

        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar(); 
        actionBar.setTitle("Reminders"); 
        FragmentManager Fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); 
        super.onStart(); 
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar(); 
        actionBar.setTitle("Reminders"); 
        FragmentManager Fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); 
        super.onResume(); 
    }
}
```

Any hints where I am going wrong would be regarded in great esteem!

Comment: Are you sure there are no other errors in your file? At times, there are a few false warnings that may pop up in Eclipse due to the presence of an unrelated error.

Comment: Nope if I comment the top two/ or bottom two arguments to the method. It works just fine. Giving me the desired animation. Though I don't get the animation on back press, which however is a different issue.

Comment: I guess I have found it, I need to do it with a back stack.. for the reverse transition.